# Что писать в action формы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! На сайте есть форма фильтра:

```
<form action="..." method="GET">
  ...
</form>
```

Если пользователь находится просто в каталоге (категория не выбрана) `action` у формы должен быть таким `action="/catalog/"` (в URL будет такой адрес `/catalog/?min_price=100&max_price=500`), а если пользователь находясь в каталоге выбрал категорию и потом решил отфильтровать не могу понять что писать в `action` формы. Конечный адрес в URL должен быть таким `/catalog/?category=ad?min_price=500&max_price=600`. В данный момент при нажатии на кнопку отфильтровать фильтр срабатывает не учитывая в каком каталоге мы находимся (т.е. адрес в URL `/catalog/?min_price=500&max_price=600`). Надеюсь все понятно разъяснил)

Comment: В  Action напишите только куда(страница) должны отправляться данные, например "/catalog", а остальные параметры GET запроса, в зависемости от выбора пользователя, добавляйте через форму (input, select)

Comment: @Arsen, сначала завести `input` с `value='category=ad'`, а в `action` прописать просто `/catalog/`?

Comment: Показал пример формы

Answer (score 2):

Простой пример:

```
<form action="/catalog" method="GET">
  <select name="category">
    <option value="catID1">Категория 1</option>
    <option value="catID2">Категория 2</option>
    <option value="catID3">Категория 3</option>
  </select>
  <select name="price_min">
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="keyword" value="">
  /* и т.д */
</form>
```

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо! Еще такой вопрос родился) Если добавить пагинацию как это будет выглядеть? Т.е. в URL будет такой адрес `/catalog/?category=ad?min_price=500&max_price=600`, что писать в кнопке пагинации (`<a class="open_page" href="???">...</a>`)? Так чтобы адрес в URL был таким `/catalog/?category=ad?min_price=500&max_price=600&page=1`

Comment: Ну вы можете просто получить current page URL, после добавить новый параметр  &page= и установить полученную строку в href=""

Answer (score 1):

В экшен вы пишите адрес скрипта получающего данные с формы. Тоесть в вашем случае следующее: `/catalog/`
При отправке формы адрес будет вида: `/catalog/?category=ad&min_price=500&max_price=600`

Comment: Принимает эта же страница. Пробовал как вы писали, не сработало

Comment: Тогда в вопросе добавьте пожалуйста код формы, будем разбираться. Я просто понял, что у вас форма уже работает...

Comment: Вам @Arsen ответил правильно :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/catalog" method="GET">
    <?= ((isset($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])) ? '<input type="hidden" name="category" value="'.$_GET["category"].'">' : '');?>
    <input type="range" min="100" max="1000" name="min_price" value="<?= (intval($_GET['max_price']) > intval($_GET['min_price']) ? intval($_GET['min_price']) : 100);?>">
    <input type="range" min="100" max="1000" name="max_price" value="<?= (intval($_GET['max_price']) > intval($_GET['min_price']) ? intval($_GET['max_price']) : 1000);?>">
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Если вы находитесь не в категории, то `<input type="hidden" name="category" value"...">` не выводится. Т. е. вы берёте значения из $_GET параметров